# How to disable possibility to type numbers in string input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have input field from which is InputText from PrimeReact and content of this field should always be text, not figures. I want to disable possibility to type figures.
Below is code example.
I also tried to make validation if typeof data is 'number' and then display comment, but data from input as I see is always a string

```
 <FloatingLabel text="Name" name={`luxmeds.${index}.persons.${idx}.name`}>
                          <StyledInputText
                            name={`luxmeds.${index}.persons.${idx}.name`}
                            value={person.name}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            type="text"
                          />
                        </FloatingLabel>
                        {!values.luxmeds[index].persons[idx].name && (
                          <StyledWarningText>{'You need to provide a name'}</StyledWarningText>
                        )}
                        {typeof values.luxmeds[index].persons[idx].name === 'number' && (
                          <StyledWarningText>{'You need to provide a name'}</StyledWarningText>
                        )}
```

Can You please suggest how to achieve that ?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just detect if the value passed to `onChange` contains a number, and if it does, do not set the state of `person.name`.

For example,

```
 const handleChange = (e) => {
      const numberRegex = /[0-9]/;
      if (!numberRegex.test(e.target.value)) {
        // set state
      }
   }
```

You might also consider using HTML5 pattern attribute:

```
                          <StyledInputText
                            name={`luxmeds.${index}.persons.${idx}.name`}
                            value={person.name}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            type="text"
                            pattern="[a-zA-Z]*"
                          />
```